# How do I get more pets for my dwellers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Fallout Shelter has a new feature where your Dwellers can also have a Pet. Is there a way to get more pets without purchasing them? Can you find them in the wasteland?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can get both [Mr.Handy's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdXeZ.jpg) and pets as objective rewards now.

Comment: I've found that you can also get the pets from lunchboxes. They seem to be pretty rare though.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the same way you get Mr. Handy, you get him with weekly lunch boxes.

or, as you say, you can buy some lunchboxes.